# Program for Odd/Even output only giving 1 answer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm stuck on an assignment needs the program to accept multiple numbers and then output "Yes" if odd and "No" if even,  and can't figure out how to make the program accept more than 1 int and then output the correct println. 
This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class odd{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      numbers[i] = in.nextInt();

      if(i % 2 == 0 )
         System.out.println("Yes");
      if( i % 2 == 1 )
         System.out.println("No");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it meant to print "yes" for even or odd? Your question says odd, but `i%2==0` would print "yes" for even numbers

Comment: I was messing with the outputs because they were giving the wrong outputs for the numbers but "yes" should be for odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store all your numbers in an array. Later loop it.

Instead of checking index value like `if(i % 2 == 0 )`, check the entered number `if(numbers[i] % 2 == 0)`.

```
  int[] numbers = new int[10];

  //storing all the numbers in an array
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      numbers[i] = in.nextInt();

  //checking each one
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
     if(numbers[i] % 2 == 0 )
         System.out.println("No");//even
     if(numbers[i] % 2 == 1 )
         System.out.println("Yes");//odd
  }
```

**Output:**

1
4
3
6
7
8
9
0
2
3
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
Yes
No

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you mean `numbers[i] % 2`, rather than `i % 2`. Otherwise, you're not using the values you are reading from `System.in`.

Note that the array is unnecessary, since you never use the array again: just declare a variable in the loop. Also, you don't need to check `<something> % 2` twice: the conditions are mutually exclusive. You can also just read until `in.hasNextInt()` is false:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
  int v = in.nextInt();
  if (v % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
  } else {
    System.out.println("No");
  }
}
```