# Encountering "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" error for assignment

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

The code works for eclipse but when I submit it to the online grader that has test cases, it's showing up as wrong because these errors come up.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at odd.main(odd.java:12)
```

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class odd{
public static void main(String args[]){


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] number = new int[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i){ 
  number[i] = sc.nextInt(9); //error here

  if ( number[i] % 2 == 0 )
     System.out.println("No");
  else
     System.out.println("Yes");
      }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34997684/3788176

Comment: Also: you don't want to use `sc.nextInt(9)`. That is reading a number in base 9. Just drop the int parameter: `sc.nextInt()` (or use 10, the default).

Comment: Sorry I created more errors after that and changed the code at point. Thanks for your help it worked with the "while" line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997684/3788176), you can just read until `in.hasNextInt()` is false:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
  int v = in.nextInt();
  if (v % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
  } else {
    System.out.println("No");
  }
}
```

This handles any number of input integers.